# Make a new column based on a condition in existing column in R

Tags: r

**Shorter version**
For each `spread_event`, I need to make a new column, based on existing `leaf_wetness_duration` column, that is TRUE is 5 hour or more than 5 hour `UNINTURRUPTED/CONTINUOUS` dry period is observed. I am not interested in each row, I am interested in a `spread_event`.

**Longer version**
I put out plants in the field for a week or `spread_event`. The weather data was recorded at 15 minutes interval, so each row represents 15 minutes duration. The column `leaf_wetness_duration` lists the duration of leaf wetness caused by rain or relative humidity. I want to test the hypothesis that whether spore can survive 5 hours or longer of `UINTURRPED` dry period or not. So if there is 1 hour dry period and 1 hour wet period, then again 1 hour wet/dry period, and 5 hour or more dry period, I want that to be FALSE because I am only interested in continuous dry period. I can calculate dry period but not sure how to calculate `UNINTERRUPTED/CONTINUOUS` dry period.

```
df %>%
group_by(spread_event) %>%
mutate (dry_period= ???) # spread event with continuous dry period of five hours or more
```

```
Spread_event        date            leaf_wetness_duration
1             8/19/15 7:15 PM                  15
1             8/19/15 7:30 PM                  2
1             8/19/15 7:45 PM                  0
1             8/19/15 8:00 PM                  0
1             8/19/15 8:15 PM                  0
1             8/19/15 8:30 PM                  0
1             8/19/15 8:45 PM                  0
1             8/19/15 9:00 PM                  0
1             8/19/15 9:15 PM                  0
1             8/19/15 9:30 PM                  0
1             8/19/15 9:45 PM                  0
1             8/19/15 10:00 PM                 0
1             8/19/15 10:15 PM                 0
1             8/19/15 10:30 PM                 0
1             8/19/15 10:45 PM                 3
```

In the above example, I can say that `UNINTURREPTED` leaf wetness duration is 180 minutes or 3 hours (12 rows with zero wetness - each row represents 15 minutes duration, 12*15 = 180 minutes). I would like to do this in R rather than manually because the data set is huge. Is there a way that can calculate `leaf_wetness_duration == 0` for 20 rows straight (without wet period in between `leaf_wetness_duration == 0`)?

Thanks

Comment: Given your example, what's your desired output?

Comment: So, to be clear, for this sample of data there the longest run of `leaf_wetness_duration == 0` is 12 rows. 12 rows is less than 20 rows (= 5 hours * 15 minutes / row), so you want a new column that is `FALSE` for every row in this sample. Correct?

Comment: @GregorThomas I am only interested in the spread event. For spread_event 1, I ONLY want it to be true if there is continuous dry period for 5 hours. So if there is 2 hour leaf_wetness_duration == 0 and then 2 h wet period leaf_wetness_duration > 0, I want that to be FALSE. Continuous or uninterrupted is the tricky part here

Comment: I can't tell if you're telling me my earlier comment is correct or incorrect. For your sample data, what is the desired result? Is it a new column that is all FALSE?

Comment: @GregorThomas Yes. I want a new column that is all FALSE if there are no 20 consecutive rows with `leaf_wetness_duration == 0` in each `spread_event`. Number of times 20 consecutive rows with `leaf_wetness_duration == 0` occurred in each `spread_event` also works

Comment: In my answer you can change to `mutate(longest_run_of_0 = with(rle(leaf_wetness_duration), max(lengths[values == 0]))` to get the get the longest run of 0s directly, then you can do whatever conditions you want on that... e.g., `longest_run_of_0 > 3 * 4 & longest_run_of_0 <= 5 * 4` for 3-5 hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `rle` function to find the longest consecutive run of 0s.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Spread_event) %>%
  mutate(
    longest_run_of_0 = with(rle(leaf_wetness_duration), max(lengths[values == 0]) >= 20)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 15 × 4
#    Spread_event date             leaf_wetness_duration longest_run_of_0
#           <int> <chr>                            <int> <lgl>           
#  1            1 8/19/15 7:15 PM                     15 FALSE           
#  2            1 8/19/15 7:30 PM                      2 FALSE           
#  3            1 8/19/15 7:45 PM                      0 FALSE           
#  4            1 8/19/15 8:00 PM                      0 FALSE           
#  5            1 8/19/15 8:15 PM                      0 FALSE           
#  6            1 8/19/15 8:30 PM                      0 FALSE           
#  7            1 8/19/15 8:45 PM                      0 FALSE           
#  8            1 8/19/15 9:00 PM                      0 FALSE           
#  9            1 8/19/15 9:15 PM                      0 FALSE           
# 10            1 8/19/15 9:30 PM                      0 FALSE           
# 11            1 8/19/15 9:45 PM                      0 FALSE           
# 12            1 8/19/15 10:00 PM                     0 FALSE           
# 13            1 8/19/15 10:15 PM                     0 FALSE           
# 14            1 8/19/15 10:30 PM                     0 FALSE           
# 15            1 8/19/15 10:45 PM                     3 FALSE
```

If you want the count of such runs instead, you can use `count = with(rle(leaf_wetness_duration), sum(lengths[values == 0] >= 20))`

---

Using this sample data

```
df = read.table(header = T, text = 'Spread_event        date            leaf_wetness_duration
1             "8/19/15 7:15 PM"                  15
1             "8/19/15 7:30 PM"                  2
1             "8/19/15 7:45 PM"                  0
1             "8/19/15 8:00 PM"                  0
1             "8/19/15 8:15 PM"                  0
1             "8/19/15 8:30 PM"                  0
1             "8/19/15 8:45 PM"                  0
1             "8/19/15 9:00 PM"                  0
1             "8/19/15 9:15 PM"                  0
1             "8/19/15 9:30 PM"                  0
1             "8/19/15 9:45 PM"                  0
1             "8/19/15 10:00 PM"                 0
1             "8/19/15 10:15 PM"                 0
1             "8/19/15 10:30 PM"                 0
1             "8/19/15 10:45 PM"                 3')
```