# Make a new column based on a condition in already existing column in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-wrangling

For each spread_event, I need to make a new column, based on existing `leaf_wetness_duration` column, that is TRUE is if more than or equal to 3 hours and less than or equal to 5 hours `UNINTURRUPTED/CONTINUOUS/CONSECUTIVE` dry period is observed.

Here is my data

```
Spread_event        date            leaf_wetness_duration
1             8/19/15 7:15 PM                  15
1             8/19/15 7:30 PM                  2
1             8/19/15 7:45 PM                  0
1             8/19/15 8:00 PM                  0
1             8/19/15 8:15 PM                  0
1             8/19/15 8:30 PM                  0
1             8/19/15 8:45 PM                  0
1             8/19/15 9:00 PM                  0
1             8/19/15 9:15 PM                  0
1             8/19/15 9:30 PM                  0
1             8/19/15 9:45 PM                  0
1             8/19/15 10:00 PM                 0
1             8/19/15 10:15 PM                 0
1             8/19/15 10:30 PM                 0
1             8/19/15 10:45 PM                 3
```

In the above example, I can say that UNINTURREPTED leaf wetness duration is 180 minutes or 3 hours (12 rows with zero wetness - each row represents 15 minutes duration, 12*15 = 180 minutes).

Here is a way to make new column that is all FALSE if there are no 20 consecutive rows with leaf_wetness_duration == 0 in each spread_event based on this answer [Make a new column based on a condition in existing column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75316357/make-a-new-column-based-on-a-condition-in-existing-column-in-r/75325004#75325004)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Spread_event) %>%
  mutate(
    longest_run_of_0 = with(rle(leaf_wetness_duration), max(lengths[values == 0]) >= 20)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 15 × 4
#    Spread_event date             leaf_wetness_duration longest_run_of_0
#           <int> <chr>                            <int> <lgl>           
#  1            1 8/19/15 7:15 PM                     15 FALSE           
#  2            1 8/19/15 7:30 PM                      2 FALSE           
#  3            1 8/19/15 7:45 PM                      0 FALSE           
#  4            1 8/19/15 8:00 PM                      0 FALSE           
#  5            1 8/19/15 8:15 PM                      0 FALSE           
#  6            1 8/19/15 8:30 PM                      0 FALSE           
#  7            1 8/19/15 8:45 PM                      0 FALSE           
#  8            1 8/19/15 9:00 PM                      0 FALSE           
#  9            1 8/19/15 9:15 PM                      0 FALSE           
# 10            1 8/19/15 9:30 PM                      0 FALSE           
# 11            1 8/19/15 9:45 PM                      0 FALSE           
# 12            1 8/19/15 10:00 PM                     0 FALSE           
# 13            1 8/19/15 10:15 PM                     0 FALSE           
# 14            1 8/19/15 10:30 PM                     0 FALSE           
# 15            1 8/19/15 10:45 PM                     3 FALSE
```

I would like to change the condition from 20 consecutive rows with `leaf_wetness_duration == 0` to consecutive greater than or equal to 12 and less than or equal to 20 rows. That is, `>=12 & <=20`. I replaced `max(lengths[values == 0] >= 20))` in the above code with `max(lengths[values == 0] >=12 & <=20))` but getting an error. I tried replacing `max` with `filter` function thinking that `filter` function would accept `&` but it didn't work. I would also like to count such run using `count = with(rle(leaf_wetness_duration), sum(lengths[values == 0] >= 20))` but the condition needs to be changed to `>=12 & <=20`.

**In summary**,
I want the same output as answered here [Make a new column based on a condition in existing column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75316357/make-a-new-column-based-on-a-condition-in-existing-column-in-r/75325004#75325004), but I just want the condition to change from 5 hour to between 3 and 5 hour (both inclusive).

Comment: It seems that your condition is based on a time-span, yet your `date` is a string. Why bother to include it if you aren't thinking to use it in your processing? Are you guaranteeing that its interval is always 15 minutes? If yes, it is not necessary to include here; if no, then it needs to be of class `POSIXt` so that you can do number-like things with it.

Comment: @r2evans My calculations are based on `leaf_wetness_duration` column, which `leaf_wetness_duration == 0` for 3 to 5 hours. Not on date column. I just checked the class of date column, it's `dttm` class. But `date` column should not affect my calculation and I'm okay with removing it. It's just to show that weather data was recorded at 15 minutes interval, so each `row` represents 15 minutes.

Comment: Yes. *"For 3 to 5 hours"*. If you _guarantee_ that every row is always exactly 15 minutes spaced, then the `date` column is meaningless in the context of this question. However, if there is even the remotest change that the row-spacing varies, then you really should use a sliding window over time, which to me means first converting the `date` column to `POSIXt` class (easy), and then using a time-based sliding window such as `slider::slide_period` with a custom function.

Comment: (I'm not suggesting that your question or its sample data are bad ... I'm suggesting that if you _want_ it to be based on time, then know that you can do it based on time, not just on the number of rows.)

Comment: @r2evans whatever works. I just need to calculate 3-5 hours continuous dry period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code was needed to get continuous 3-5 hour leaf wetness duration

```
df %>%
group_by(spread_event) %>%
dry_period_3_5 = with(rle(leaf_wetness_duration), sum(lengths[values == 0] >= 12 & lengths[values == 0] <= 20))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have enough data to challenge the 3-5 hours constraint, I'm going to demonstrate 1 and 2 hours instead: if there is 1 hour of uninterrupted `duration==0` and *not* 2 hours of uninterrupted `==0`. For this, I'll create *two* columns: one that indicates 1h (your 3h), and one that indicates 2h (your 5h), and from that you can use the combination to infer you desired logic.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(slider) # slide_period_lgl
df %>%
  group_by(Spread_event) %>%
  mutate(
    date = as.POSIXct(date, format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M %p"),
    run1h = slider::slide_period_lgl(
      .x = leaf_wetness_duration, .i = date,
      .period = "minute", .before = 60,
      .f = ~ all(.x == 0)),
    run2h = slider::slide_period_lgl(
      .x = leaf_wetness_duration, .i = date,
      .period = "minute", .before = 120,
      .f = ~ all(.x == 0)),
    result1 = run1h & !run2h,
    result2 = any(result1)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 15 × 7
#    Spread_event date                leaf_wetness_duration run1h run2h result1 result2
#           <int> <dttm>                              <int> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>   <lgl>  
#  1            1 2015-08-19 07:15:00                    15 FALSE FALSE FALSE   TRUE   
#  2            1 2015-08-19 07:30:00                     2 FALSE FALSE FALSE   TRUE   
#  3            1 2015-08-19 07:45:00                     0 FALSE FALSE FALSE   TRUE   
#  4            1 2015-08-19 08:00:00                     0 FALSE FALSE FALSE   TRUE   
#  5            1 2015-08-19 08:15:00                     0 FALSE FALSE FALSE   TRUE   
#  6            1 2015-08-19 08:30:00                     0 FALSE FALSE FALSE   TRUE   
#  7            1 2015-08-19 08:45:00                     0 TRUE  FALSE TRUE    TRUE   
#  8            1 2015-08-19 09:00:00                     0 TRUE  FALSE TRUE    TRUE   
#  9            1 2015-08-19 09:15:00                     0 TRUE  FALSE TRUE    TRUE   
# 10            1 2015-08-19 09:30:00                     0 TRUE  FALSE TRUE    TRUE   
# 11            1 2015-08-19 09:45:00                     0 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE   TRUE   
# 12            1 2015-08-19 10:00:00                     0 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE   TRUE   
# 13            1 2015-08-19 10:15:00                     0 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE   TRUE   
# 14            1 2015-08-19 10:30:00                     0 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE   TRUE   
# 15            1 2015-08-19 10:45:00                     3 FALSE FALSE FALSE   TRUE
```

Comment: See my (most-recent) edit adding `result1` and `result2`, where I think you're looking for `result2`?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I'm interested in spread_event NOT each row.  My condition is 3-5 wet hours for each spread_event. If this conditions is satisfied, then I should get one TRUE value for the entire spread_event and vice versa. In the above, example the condition max(lengths[values == 0]) >= 20 has not met, so I have one FALSE for the entire spread event. Then in ANOTHER column, I'd like to know how many times that condition was TRUE.

Comment: Um. You said you want the same value for the entire spread event, and ... now you want to know how many times this condition (which is the same value across the entire `Spread_event` is true for that spread event? That would be always `0` or `n()`. My answer provides the ability to check between two time ranges: 1 and 2h (actually, `60` and `120` _minutes_), just change to `180` and `300` for your code. If this still doesn't work for you, then please update your sample data so that there is some variance. Also, for brevity, let's go with shorter intervals with expected output please.